# Django on GAE - name 'url' is not defined

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I've just uploaded my django web app to GAE, but I'm getting an error when I compile it with "dev_appserver.py":

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    name 'url' is not defined
```

Here my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

 urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^landing/$', 'webpage_dev.dashboard.views.landing'),
)
```

I'm importing url from django.conf.urls.default. Why appear this error?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
```

Comment: After change my code with "from django.conf.urls import *", the following error appears:

Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: cannot import name url

Comment: check the indentation, maybe you use tab, just use spaces and I update my answer. I back your original code

Comment: here my code: `from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url`

and here my error again: 

`Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: cannot import name url`

It still doesn't work

Comment: I figured out the problem. Here the solution:

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *